# Magento2: Function of enable/disable (yes/no) button for any module

Tags: magento2, admin, custom-button, data-bind, new-shipment

I Have a module for the **new shipment method** with **dropdown option (yes/no)**, to enable and disable the module function. I want to know how the module function works off while select No, and module work starts while select Yes. how is module bind with on the button enable/disable the function.
please check below module code and images.
/Packt/Shipme/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Packt_Shipme',
    __DIR__
);
```

/Packt/Shipme/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Packt_Shipme" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Shipping"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

/Packt/Shipme/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/con
fig.xsd">
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <shipme>
                <model>Packt\Shipme\Model\Carrier\Shipme</model>
                <active>1</active>
                <name>Shipme Shipping</name>
                <title>Shipme Shipping</title>
                <express_enabled>1</express_enabled>
                <express_title>Express delivery</express_title>
                <express_price>4</express_price><business_enabled>1</business_enabled>
                <business_title>Business delivery</business_title>
                <business_price>5</business_price>
                <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is currently unavailable.
                    If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact
                    us.</specificerrmsg>
            </shipme>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

/Packt/Shipme/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="carriers"><group id="shipme" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50"
                                      showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Shipme</label>
            <field id="active" translate="label" type="select"
                   sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Enabled</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>

            <field id="name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20"
                   showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Method Name</label>
            </field>
            <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20"
                   showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Method Title</label>
            </field>
            <field id="express_enabled" translate="label" type="select"
                   sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0"><label>Enable express</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="express_title" translate="label" type="text"
                   sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Title express</label>
            </field>
            <field id="express_price" translate="label" type="text"
                   sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Price express</label>
            </field>
            <field id="business_enabled" translate="label" type="select"
                   sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Enable business</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="business_title" translate="label" type="text"
                   sortOrder="70" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Title business</label>
            </field>
            <field id="business_price" translate="label" type="text"
                   sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Price business</label>
            </field>
            <field id="specificerrmsg" translate="label" type="textarea"
                   sortOrder="90" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Displayed Error Message</label>
            </field>
            <field id="sallowspecific" translate="label" type="select"
                sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                <source_model>Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect"
                sortOrder="110" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
            </field>
        </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

/Packt/Shipme/Model/Carrier/Shipme.php

```
<?php
namespace Packt\Shipme\Model\Carrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
class Shipme extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface {
    protected $_code = 'shipme';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    protected $_rateMethodFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory
        $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
        $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger,
            $data);
    }
    public function
    collectRates(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request) {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
//Check if express method is enabled
        if ($this->getConfigData('express_enabled')) {
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);$method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
            $method->setMethod('express');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('express_title'));
            $method->setPrice($this->getConfigData('express_price'));
            $method->setCost($this->getConfigData('express_price'));
            $result->append($method);
        }
//Check if business method is enabled
        if ($this->getConfigData('business_enabled')) {
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
            $method->setMethod('business');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('business_title'));
            $method->setPrice($this->getConfigData('business_price'));
            $method->setCost($this->getConfigData('business_price'));
            $result->append($method);
        }
        return $result;
        }
         public function getAllowedMethods() {
            return ['shipme' => $this->getConfigData('name')];
        }
            public function isTrackingAvailable()
        {
           return true;
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code in `config.xml` makes your module Enabled as default on installation `<active>1</active>`

Next, these lines of code in your `shipme.php` file tell the system to check if it is enabled or not.

```
protected $_code = 'shipme';
if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
     return false;
}
```

This is how the system knows if your module is enabled or not.

Comment: yes,thats right

Comment: how can I cross-check that the above code is responsible for module enable/disable.

Comment: Comment out the if condition, and then you can cross-check that above code is responsible for module enable/disable