# Magento module onboarding

Tags: magento2

I am creating a custom Magento 2 module. In Wordpress/Shopify, when installing plugin/extension it shows the onboarding form where the merchant can fill in all the information used by the plugin to run. For example, my module needs to know the merchant's name, address, etc...

However, when installing a new module in Magento 2, I see no onboarding. And I don't know how to do it in Magento 2. The merchant can't use my module if they don't answer some questions :)

Could you show me how to do that in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right what you need is to make the merchant insert the values on a form and don't have a default value right?
I don't think you can do that, might be wrong tho, but the best solution I can think of is to have some default values, have some condition that whatever the module doesn't work and show a warning if the values are the default ones, and create a tab in admin so the merchant can insert the info you need btw it might help, you can get some on the information the is already in the system like store address, store name, etc etc...

Sorry if I understood it incorrectly :D

EDIT:
Something like this [image]

And if the "Page Title" is "Some value" block the "Module Enable" dropdown, that way you force the merchant to change that field to something else, do it for all the fields needed

Comment: There are some fields that I cannot provide default value or get that value from store

Comment: Try to make the default value like an empty or name it even default value and then do a condition to check that value, do a admin form and if the value is the one you put as default throw a warning or something and force the module to be disabled, until that value is not the default one the merchant can't change it to enable

Comment: Do you have any code example?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296553/magento2-function-of-enable-disable-yes-no-button-for-any-module
I don't atm and might take a while to do one as example so for now I think this might be a good referente to create the form at admin. I think that in that line of code that checks if the module is active or not you can add another condition that checks if the other fields are the default ones. `if($this->getConfigData('page_title')=="default value" || !$this->getConfigFlag('active')` return false and some warning i guess (didn't test it tho)